# Alternator without a battery

Tags: dc-motor

Can I run a 24 volt DC motor with current from a 24 volt alternator, with bridge rectifier, without having a battery in the system anywhere?

Comment: Depends on the alternator. Most of the automotive ones require external DC (battery) for magnetization. Permanent magnet ones do not.

Comment: The output of an automotive alternator wil be DC with some ripple - no need for an additional rectifier.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the alternator is a voltage controlled 3 phase full-wave rectified current source without a smoothing capacitor.  The current source is regulated by the voltage error from 14.2V by the field current modulating the output current.

The battery being effectively a very large capacitor (>> xxx,xxx Farads) with low ESR (0.0x ohms) reduces the ripple and the ESR provides the necessary load regulator error.
**%V error=~ I load*ESR/R load**

So the resulting ripple error will depend on the ESR and C and load spectrum from DC to f.

### Conclusion

It likely will operate with a peak voltage in the range of the expected battery voltage but with a very large ripple voltage .  Performance of any load highly depends on the need for some battery or ultracap and RLC response with step loads.

Answer (score 0):

Research 'alternator load dump'. If the load is constant, it'll probably be OK, but if there is an interruption, the alternator output can rise quite dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I run a 24 volt DC motor with current from a 24 volt alternator, with bridge rectifier, without having a battery in the system anywhere?

Not if it's a self-excited automotive alternator, having its rectified output feeding its field winding, through an 'on-off' regulator switching the excitation current between 2 set points (27.6 & 28.4 V). The battery would be required to excite the field to start with and later to maintain its output voltage stable, in the range 27.6 - 28.4 V.

On the other hand, an alternator with a permanent magnet rotor would not require a battery for its functioning. However, it would require a shunt regulator to maintain its output voltage at 24 V.